# backup Vagrant Mysql with mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, vagrant, mysql-workbench

I am running scotch box vagrant box.

I am using Mysql Workbench to connect to it.

Connect to the database is not an issue, using "Standard TCP/IP over SSH

[image]

However , I am trying to use MySQL Workbench, "Export Data" feature to back up the database.

- Click "Export Data"
- Check the box next to the schema I want to back up
- Click "Start Export"

But it always returns the error:

```
05:26:20 Dumping databasename (tablename)
Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump
--defaults-file="/var/folders/x1/h3dh_9hn4xz75qmz1tyjg7980000gn/T/tmpBMusBi/extraparams.cnf
"  --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=21651 
--default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "database name" "table name"

mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server 
on 'localhost' (61) when trying to connect
```

How can I get the data export to work properly?

Comment: You can actually connect with WB to that server? If the connection from WB works then it should also work from mysqldump.

Comment: yes, connecting, updating rows, adding schema and tables, none of it is an issue, its just when it comes to using the "export data" feature that I have the issue,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most elegant fix, but it works

Updated vagrant file

```
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
```

add provisioning

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

sudo sed -i 's/bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

sudo service mysql restart

SHELL
```

run:

```
vagrant provision
```

Connect to database

add new user

```
User: root
From host: %
```

ensure new user has full privileges

create a new database connection with the following settings

```
connection method: standard (tcp/ip)
hostname: 192.168.33.10
username: root
```

When you connect to database using this connection, the "export Data" function will work correctly.